# For loop with if condition on multiple R functions

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I'm new to programming and don't quite understand the logic behind functions in R just yet. I want to create a function which is able to handle four variables, with conditions in three of these deciding the result in the fourth variable; and that goes through all cases in the data set. For the sake of simplicity, lets say my data frame has four variables (var1 to var4) with 100 cases each:

```
f1 <- function(w, x, y, z) {
   for (n in seq_along(w)) {
    if (!is.na(w[n]) & !is.na(x[n]) & !is.na(y[n])){
  z[n]<-0
}else if (!is.na(w[n]) & !is.na(x[n]) & is.na(y[n])){
  z[n]<-1
}else if (!is.na(w[n]) & is.na(x[n]) & is.na(y[n])){
  z[n]<-2
}else if (!is.na(w[n]) & is.na(x[n]) & !is.na(y[n])){
  z[n]<-3
} } }
```

`f1(df$var1, df$var2, df$var3, df$var4)`

Why doesn't the function work?

Comment: maybe a return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `z` that you are modifying inside `f1` is a local copy and doesn't get updated in the original data-set `df`. You need to return the modified `z` and assign it to `var4` in `df`.

```
f1 <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  for (n in seq_along(w)) {
    if (!is.na(w[n]) & !is.na(x[n]) & !is.na(y[n])){
      z[n]<-0
    } else if (!is.na(w[n]) & !is.na(x[n]) & is.na(y[n])) {
      z[n]<-1
    } else if (!is.na(w[n]) & is.na(x[n]) & is.na(y[n])) {
      z[n]<-2
    } else if (!is.na(w[n]) & is.na(x[n]) & !is.na(y[n])) {
      z[n]<-3
    } 
  } 
  z  # <--- return value 
}
```

Then call `f1` as:

```
df$var4 <- f1(df$var1, df$var2, df$var3, df$var4)
```